# Implementing DataTables into my Laravel project.

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

I have an existing Laravel project, and was introduced to DataTables just recently and liked the features it had, so I wanted to implement it into my project.  I've followed the guide but for some reason the search, pagination, and filters don't show up on my tables, but the actual table does display.

I think I installed the assets in my master view incorrectly, that's the only reason I can think of, any help would be great.

**Resource Controller**

```html
public function resource()
{
 $resources = Resource::with('locations')->get();

 return view('pages.resource', compact('resources'));
}
```

**Route**

```html
Route::get('resource', array('as'=>'viewResource', 'uses' => 'ResourceController@resource'));
```

**Master View (app.blade.php)**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  
......

@yield('scripts')
<!-- Bootstrap Based Data Table Plugin Script-->
  
<script src="code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"></script>
        
<script src="cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  
</body>
</html>
```

**resource.blade.php**

```html
div class="wrapper">
    <section class="panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <b> Resource Info</b>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
            <table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Address</th>
                    <th>City</th>
                    <th>Zip Code</th>
                    <th>County</th>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                @foreach($resources as $resource)
                    @foreach ($resource->locations as $location)
                        <tr>
                            <td> {{ $resource->Name }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $resource->Description }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $location->Address }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $location->City }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $location->Zip_Code }}</td>
                            <td> {{ $location->County }}</td>
                        </tr>
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>
    </div>
    @section('scripts')
     <script>
        $('.resource').DataTable({
            select:true,
            "order": [[0, "desc"]],
            "scrollY"   :"380px",
            "scrollCollapse": true,
            "paging"    :true,
            "bProcessing"   :true
        });
    </script>
    
    @stop
```

**output**
[image]

Comment: As an unrelated note, you should replace `bProcessing` with `processing`; the former is the pre-v1.10 notation. It will work but is inconsistent with the rest of your notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leon is close, but what you actually need to do is run the jQuery to initialize the DataTables on the *ID* of the table, which you currently don't have. Consider modifying your setup like so:

```
<table class="display table table-hover table-bordered", id="TABLENAME">
```

Note that in addition to adding an ID to the table, I also added the `display` class, which is part of the DataTables requirements. In addition to that change, you'll also have to change the DataTable initialization to:

```
$('#TABLENAME').DataTable({
```

to allow it to be turned into a DataTable. (Fill in `TABLENAME` with whatever you want, just make sure it matches the HTML table `id`)

From your output, it looks like you are getting just a pure HTML table, without any DataTables features. These two changes should give you a proper DataTable.

Comment: Thank you! That seems to be what I was missing, but now I get an alert with  `DataTables warning: table id=resource - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1` whenever I try to do anything with the tables.

Comment: @ph0bolus Check the JSON being sent to and from the server (using developer tools or Fiddler). There' s some problem with the format (this is unrelated to your initial question). Look at that datatables.net page for more information on diagnosing. It's odd that you get that since I don't see you using ajax for the data which is what usually causes it.

Comment: I checked the datatables.net page, but it didn't help much in figuring out the problem, so by trial and error I was able to fix the problem by just deleting a line I had added before posting, it was `serverSide: true,` in the DataTable declaration.

Comment: @ph0bolus Oh, that will definitely cause that error. ServerSide requires your server to do all the processing/sorting/filtering of the data instead of the plugin doing it automatically, and it sends/recieves JSON data to a handler to do that. Since you didn't have the handler in place you got `invalid JSON`.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you need to add the class you are using as your datatables handle to the actual table.

So

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered">
```

should become,

```
<table class="table table-hover table-bordered resource">
```

If you are using Laravel the following package also integrates nicely with fetching content via ajax: https://github.com/yajra/laravel-datatables

Comment: Thanks, I've added `resource` to the table class, but it didn't change a thing.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know the Laravel Datatables project http://datatables.yajrabox.com/ ?

I use it in my Laravel projects and works fantastic.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm currently using.